# Testing component is using the original service and not spying it

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

When I test if the button is clicked and it calls the onSignIn() method on the component this test pass.

But when I try to test if the onSignIn() calls signIn() method on the AuthService, the test not pass and call the original service doing a network call.

Here is my code:

**sign-in.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { faTimes } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { AuthService } from '../../core';
import { AlertService, FormErrorHandler } from '../../shared';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-in',
  templateUrl: './sign-in.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-in.component.scss']
})
export class SignInComponent implements OnInit {
  signInForm!: FormGroup;
  ...

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private alertService: AlertService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    ...
  }
  ...

  onSignIn() {
    ...

    this.authService
      .signIn(this.signInForm.value)
      .subscribe(
        user => {
          this.authService.setSession(user, this.rememberMe.value);
          this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
        },
        error => {
          if (error instanceof Object) {
            FormErrorHandler.errorHandler(this.signInForm, error);
          } else {
            this.alertService.error(error);
          }
        }
      );
  }
}
```

**sign-in.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AuthRoutingModule } from './auth-routing.module';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule  } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared';
import { AuthComponent } from './auth.component';
import { SignInComponent } from './sign-in/sign-in.component';
import { SignUpComponent } from './sign-up/sign-up.component';
import { PasswordRecoverComponent } from './password-recover/password-recover.component';
import { PasswordResetComponent } from './password-reset/password-reset.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AuthComponent,
    SignInComponent,
    SignUpComponent,
    PasswordRecoverComponent,
    PasswordResetComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AuthRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { config } from '../../../config';
import { User } from '../../../shared';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthService {
  public isAuthenticated = false;
  public authStatusSubject = new Subject<boolean>();
  public currentUserId = '';
  public currentUserToken = '';

  get id() { return localStorage.getItem('id'); }

  get token() { return localStorage.getItem('token'); }

  get expiration() { return localStorage.getItem('expires_at'); }

  getAuthStatusSubject() { return this.authStatusSubject.asObservable(); }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {}
  ...

  signIn(user: User) {
    return this.http.post<{
        message: string;
        user: { id: string; token: string; expiresAt: string };
      }>(`${config.URL}/api/auth/login`, {
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password
      })
      .pipe(map(data => { return data.user; }));
  }

  setSession(user, rememberMe: boolean) {
    if (rememberMe) {
      const expiresAt = new Date(user.expiresAt);
      localStorage.setItem('id', user.id);
      localStorage.setItem('token', user.token);
      localStorage.setItem('expires_at', expiresAt.toUTCString());
    }
    this.isAuthenticated = true;
    this.authStatusSubject.next(true);
    this.currentUserId = user.id;
    this.currentUserToken = user.token;
  }
  ...
}
```

The AuthService is provided in the core.module

**core.module.ts**

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { HeaderComponent } from './components';
import { AuthService, UserService } from './services';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ HeaderComponent ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    NgbModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    UserService
  ],
  exports: [ HeaderComponent ]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

**sign-in.component.spec.ts**

```
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AbstractControl, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { AuthService, CoreModule } from '../../core';
import { SharedModule } from '../../shared';
import { SignInComponent } from './sign-in.component';

describe('SignInComponent', () => {
  let signInComponent: SignInComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SignInComponent>;
  let signInButton: any;
  let authService: AuthService;
  ...

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [SignInComponent],
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
        FontAwesomeModule,
        CoreModule,
        SharedModule
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents()
      .then(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SignInComponent);
        signInComponent = fixture.componentInstance;
        signInComponent.ngOnInit();

        authService = TestBed.get(AuthService);
      });
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(signInComponent).toBeTruthy();
  });

  describe('#form', () => {
    describe('#signInButton', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        signInButton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button[type=submit]')).nativeElement;
      });

      it('should render button for submit form', () => {
        expect(signInButton).toBeTruthy();
      });

      it('should sign in when submited', () => {
        spyOn(signInComponent, 'onSignIn');
        spyOn(authService, 'signIn');

        signInForm.triggerEventHandler('submit', null);

        expect(signInComponent.onSignIn).toHaveBeenCalled(); // This test pass
        expect(authService.signIn).toHaveBeenCalled(); // This test fails and do a network call.
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Don't spy on the component you're testing. Use the TestBed to provide test doubles for its collaborators, not recreate the real app. See e.g. https://angular.io/guide/testing, https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/16/async-angular-tests.html

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @jonrsharpe . Spying is the only way I know to know if the component's method has been called or triggered,
Why do you say that I should not spy on the component's method?

By the way, spying on the component method works, but what does not work for me is spying on the service method and I do not understand why, it should be called once the component method is triggered.

Comment: I say you shouldn't spy on the component's method because the component is the unit you're testing, and you should test its *behaviour* not its implementation. The service isn't called *because* you spy on the component method, too; you don't call through.

Comment: If the call to the service is within the onSignIn() method of the component, this is not part of its behavior, then, I should not test that onSignIn() is called and it invokes a service method, right? I should only test that the component's method is called, not if it is calling the service, right?

Comment: No that's exactly wrong. You should test that it's calling the service with the right data when the inputs are filled and the button is clicked, what method gets called is an implementation detail you should be free to refactor.